# How to give jsp path to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I have a jsp page which is

> "addSource.jsp"

present in eclipse as shown in the picture.
[image]

Now my question is i have a javascript function where i have to give "addSource.jsp" in it so that it can move to that page from the current jsp page on button click.The code is as follows

```
 function addRow(type) {  
         if (type == '') {
                alert("Field is empty");
            }
         else {
         var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
         var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table
         var columnCount =  table.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table          
         var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row            



         var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //create a new cell           
         var element1 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
         element1.type = "text"; //set the element type 
         element1.setAttribute('id', 'source'); //set the id attribute 
         element1.setAttribute('name','source'+rowCount);
         element1.setAttribute('value',type);
         cell1.appendChild(element1);

         }


         }

    function generate1() {
             var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
             var rowCount = table.rows.length;
             alert(rowCount);
             var f = document.form;
             f.target="";
             f.method="post";
             f.action= 'addSource.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;



         }  

     <form id="form">

                       <input type="text" id="origin" name="element"/>




                      <table id="my_table">
                                <thead><tr>

                                        <th>Source</th>


                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>





                        <input type="button" value="Add row"  name="add" onClick="addRow(document.forms[0].element.value)"  />
                        <input type="submit" value=" Save" />
```

Comment: Show you just need an `onclick` event at your form?

Comment: Consider using MVC

Comment: @ScaryWombat You mean creating class file rather than using jsp??

Comment: POST/GET to servlets and use JSP for display

Comment: Here the question in my mind is i have dynamically added textbox values. I thought of posting into servlets but couldn't found a way on how to post some 10 dynamically textbox values or 15 . I edited my post for some better understanding. please refer to it

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz, are you using some kind of frameworks for your project? Since your `views` folder containing jsp pages are under `WEB-INF` which is private and not directly exposed with public access.

Comment: @Arvind yes i am using frameworks for my project.

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz, in that case kindly do the mapping of controller with the relevant view in order to complete page request.

Comment: @Arvind I thought of mapping it to controller but here some doubts are in mind.   1.Its dynamically created textboxes so if a user sends some 15 values or 20 values how to get those values in the controller . I can send the rowcount to the controller but i don't know i can get all those values in the controller. if you have any resource on that then it will be helpful.

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz, in case this is Spring MVC framework, you have to change the naming for dynamic html text-boxes starting  with index `0` to `N`, along with index notation, so it would be 
`element1.setAttribute('name','source['+rowCount+']');`. Also in controller, you would need to handle `(@RequestParam List<String> source)`

Comment: @Arvind Yes its a Spring MVC framework .I will replace that with what you said

Comment: @Arvind  Now passing into controller will be this or something else.   location.href = 'create/add/source['+rowCount+']')

Comment: @FIFAoneterahertz, there is no need for `rowCount` in the link, also **submit form** instead of using *location.href*

Comment: @Arvind  Okay. thanks . i will try what you said and update you

Comment: @Arvind Thanks for suggesting Controller part. It worked. But i changed entire javascript now i am getting the values.I am posting what i did  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x=1
    function appendRow(type)
    {
       var d = document.getElementById('div');
       d.innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='source' name='source' value='"+ type +"'><br >";
    }

 <form action="Source" method="post">

                       <input type="text" id="origin" name="origin"/>




                    <div id="div">
 <button onclick ="appendRow(document.forms[0].origin.value)" value="Add Row">Add Row</button>
 </div>          
                        <input type="submit" name="Save" value=" Save" />


                             <hr/>
                    </form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Source",params="Save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String source(Model model,HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res,@RequestParam("source") List<String> ola) {
        System.out.println("size is:" +ola.size());
        for(int i=0; i<ola.size() ;i++) {
            String srh = ola.get(i);
                    System.out.println("srh value is:" +srh);
        }

        return "redirect:/createPoints";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location.href` Add an `id` to your form (for example `formId`) and use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("formId").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "addSource.jsp";
};
```

Comment: document.getElementById("formId").onclick = function () { var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
         var rowCount = table.rows.length;
         alert(rowCount);
    location.href ='addSource.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;
};

Comment: I will edit the question for some more understanding ability

Comment: You are using two times the `document.getElementById`. This wont work. Use just the element you want to handle the event.

Comment: Here the thing i have one button onClick which is "AddRow()". once i click it then dynamically textboxes will be created along with values . So i used one more document.getElementById so that i can get "rowCount" in the sense how many textbox values is created.